# Append variable in shell

Tags: shell

The following code does not output "hello world"
I do not want to use standard out unless I have to.

```
#!/bin/sh

message="hello "
message.="world"

echo $message
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use variable expansion to achieve this:

```
#!/bin/sh

message="hello "
message="${message}world"

echo $message
```

Answer (score 0):

the following works:

```
#!/bin/sh

message="hello "
message="$message world"

echo $message
```